# Why standard deviation of uniform distribution calculated with pymc.Uniform("stds",0,100) is different each time?

Tags: python, pymc, uniform-distribution

Why standard deviation of uniform distribution calculated with pymc.Uniform("stds",0,100) is different each time?

I think standard deviation is calculated with this formula '(100-0)/2√3', so I think there is only one value with one uniform distribution.

What is pymc.Uniform doing? 
If you know the information about pymc.Uniform with "std", please teach me.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Standard Deviation should output the same value every time if the data is not changing.

(Basic breakdown of standard deviation) https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation-formulas.html

I don't know much about pymc functions, but if you can, I would highly recommend using numpy's Standard deviation function.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html

It is very simple to use and intuitive.  I have used it in several projects myself and haven't noticed a changing standard deviation.  Sorry I couldn't help you with pymc, but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You know that your standard deviation value will converge to the same value if you simulate N observations of Uniform distribution in the interval [0,100]

But the standard deviation in a frequentist point of view is a computation made on the simulated observations, not on the probability distribution. That's why you can observe difference between stds in sample datasets from the same distribution.

The standard deviation of the random variable following a uniform distribution is

`(b-a)^2 / 12`

But the estimation of the standard deviation of a sample dataset is done with a formula like this one (take a look at the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation))

`1/(n-1) * sum( (x_i - avg(X))^2 for i in 1...N )`

So try increasing number of points you simulate and you should see the difference between stds reduce

Comment: I think I could understand your answer,I just conclude this code "import pymc as pm
print(pm.Uniform("stds",0,100).value)" each time pritnted value is different. I

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I made a huge mistake. I thought pymc.Uniform("stds",0,100) do something like calculate standard deviation of uniform distribution. But it just make uniform distribution and just get one of that as value named "stds". thank you for your answer!